# Detail part of the screen is not displaying

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

In powerbuilder, there are 2 data windows for one screen.Header part is simple datawindow and the detail part is a multi row data window.Both the data windows are displaying in powerbuilder application window.But in runtime environment(exe), the header of that screen is displaying but detail of that screen is not displaying(multi row data window).could someone suggest to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is read the id from master dw and do a retrive.

It could look like :

dw_detail.retrieve(myIdFromMasterDw)

Comment: Thanks it was worked but instead of giving reading ID and retrieve, I added master datawindow fields to datawindow and datawindow fields to master datawindow